# TypeError: transactionContract.getAllTransactions is not a function at getAllTransactions (TransactionContext.jsx:40:61) at checkIfWalletIsConnected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

What does this Typeerror mean? [Type Error for getAllTransactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1rZc.png)
See portion of code below. I declared getAllTransactions as a function so I am not sure why the error message is saying that it is not a function. I checked to see if getAllTransactions was typed correctly. I am not expecting any console errors in the browser. How do i resolve this error?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {ethers} from 'ethers'
import { contractABI, contractAddress } from "../utils/constants" 
export const TransactionContext = React.createContext()

const { ethereum } = window;

const createEthereumContract = async () => {
  
  const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
  
  const signer = await provider.getSigner();
  const transactionContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);

  return transactionContract;
};

//function to check if a wallet is connected at the start
export const TransactionProvider = ({children}) => {
  
  const [formData, setformData] = useState({ addressTo: "", amount: "", keyword: "", message: "" });
  const [currentAccount, setCurrentAccount] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [transactionCount, setTransactionCount] = useState(localStorage.getItem("transactionCount"));
  const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState([]);
  
  //handleChange func interact with inputs except the event
  const handleChange = (e, name) => {
    setformData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: e.target.value }));
  };

  const getAllTransactions = async () =>{
    //check if browser has metamask installed
    try {if(!ethereum) return alert("Please install metamask")

    const transactionContract = createEthereumContract();
    const availableTransactions = await transactionContract.getAllTransactions();
    
    //change structure of data 
    const structuredTransactions = availableTransactions.map((transaction)=>({
      addressTo: transaction.receiver,
      addressFrom: transaction.sender,
      timestamp: new Date(transaction.timestamp.toNumber() * 1000).toLocaleString(),
      message: transaction.message,
      keyword: transaction.keyword,
      amount: parseInt(transaction.amount._hex) / (10 ** 18)
    }))

    console.log(structuredTransactions)

    } catch(error){
      console.log(error);

    }
  }


  const checkIfWalletIsConnected = async() =>{
    try{
      if(!ethereum) return alert("Please install metamask")
      const accounts = await ethereum.request({method:'eth_accounts'})
      console.log(accounts)

      if(accounts.length){
        setCurrentAccount(accounts[0])

        getAllTransactions()

      } else {
        console.log('No accounts found')
      }
    } catch(error){
      console.log(error)
      throw new Error("No ethereum object")
    }
  }



  const sendTransaction = async () => {
    try {
      if (ethereum) {
        const { addressTo, amount, keyword, message } = formData;
        const transactionContract = createEthereumContract();
        const parsedAmount = ethers.parseEther(amount);

        await ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_ction",
          params: [{
            from: currentAccount,
            to: addressTo,
            gas: "0x5208",
            value: parsedAmount._hex,
          }],
        });
  
  return(
<TransactionContext.Provider value={{connectWallet, currentAccount,formData,handleChange,sendTransaction,transactions,isLoading}}>
  {children} 
  
  {/*whatever we wrap inside of this transaction provider is going to be rented and 
  its going to have access to this value object*/}

</TransactionContext.Provider>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

`createEthereumContract()` is an asynchronous function, so you have to wait for it to be done. Otherwise the variable `transactionContract` will have no set value and you won't be able to access the function `getAllTransactions()`.

```
const transactionContract = await createEthereumContract();
```

Comment: Thanks it works! In addition i also realise that in sendTransaction there is some typo ``` await ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_ction",
          params: [{
            from: currentAccount,
            to: addressTo,
            gas: "0x5208",
            value: parsedAmount._hex,
          }]``` method is: "eth_sendTransaction" not "eth_ction"